# How to register complex hotkeys

Tags: windows, hotkeys

I have a very long list of things I want to trigger with hotkeys in windows. (Unmuting, Playing a soundfile, muting). I have more than 100 soundfiles I want to reach that way, so the normal combinations of windows-hotkeys are not enough (since I do not want to override shortcuts already used by other programs).

My idea is to have something similar to ASCII-codes, where you press ALT-152 to get ÿ for example. Do you know of any tool that allows something like that?

I already tried to use ÿ directly as a hotkey, but that does not seem to work.

Edit: I already tried using autohotkey, but did not manage to achieve my goals (see comment to Santis answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which allows you to program keyboard shortcuts. I always have used it with the classic accelerators (CTRL, ALT, WIN...), but I know it allows [two-keys shortcuts](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Features).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mentioned that I tried AutoHotkey. The classic Accelerators are not enough for me, as I do not want to override hotkeys from other programs). The two-key-shortcuts of autokey also do not allow something like ALT-152 to do something. I tried using the two-keys shortcuts, but the problem is, that the first key of the two-key-hotkey is blocked for other usage as it is intercepted by AutoHotkey. E.g. if i use q&a as a hotkey, I cannot use the q-key anymore.

Comment: Hum... And what about  context sensitive hotkeys (http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context)? Isn't it useful in your case?

Comment: No, not really.. but your link to the context sensitive hotkeys pointed me to a good place in the docu. I found out, that I can use something like this: ~1 & Numpad1:: to get  100 possible combinations. The ~ makes sure, that pressing 1 still gives me a 1, and i can still use it in hotkeys.